# mongoose multi-field key validator does not fail with duplicate key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose.
I've got schema defined something like this:

```
thingModel = new Schema({
  a : { type: String, index: true },
  b : { type: String, index: true }
});
thingModel.index( { a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true } );  // multifield key

module.exports = mongoose.model('Thing', thingModel);
```

elsewhere...

```
new1 = new Thing({a:1, b:2});
new1.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(error('error saving doc:',err))});

new2 = new Thing({a:1, b:2}); // same data as new1
new2.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(error('error saving doc:',err));
});
```

Shouldn't the 2nd .save return a duplicate key error?  Why am I not getting an error?
The duplicate data is getting into the database.

Mongoose v5.10.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/indexes.html)

> Compound indexes are defined on the Schema itself.

So, for multiple index, you have to defined in this way:

```js
const thingModel = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    a : { type: String }, //not index here
    b : { type: String }
  }
)
thingModel.index( { a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true } );
```

And trying to save the values with same index the error is thrown:

> E11000 duplicate key error dup key: { : "1", : "2" }

Comment: Thanks.  But, what if I need the individual fields to be indexed separately as well?  Or are they effectively indexed separately anyway with thingModel.index() ?

Answer (score 0):

A better test than demonstrates @J.F.'s compound index works.

models/thingModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true); // fixes deprecation warning
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true); 
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true); 

const thingModel = new Schema({
    a : { type: String },
    b : { type: String }
},{strict: false});
thingModel.index({ a:1, b:1 }, { unique: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Thing', thingModel);
```

./thingTest.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Thing = require('./models/thingModel');

run().catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
async function run() {
  try {
    let db = await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/things');
    await Thing.deleteMany({});
    
    let new1 = new Thing({a:"1", b:"2"});
    let new2 = new Thing({a:"1", b:"3"});
    let new3 = new Thing({a:"1", b:"2"}); // same as new 1
    await new1.save();
    await new2.save();
    await new3.save(); // throws: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: things.things index: a_1_b_1 dup key: { a: "1", b: "2" }
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  finally {
    await mongoose.connection.close();
  }
}
```